# JBoss EAP7.1 Integrated ActiveMQ Artemis message redistribution in cluster mode does not work

Tags: jboss, activemq-artemis

After following item 29 of the https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuring_messaging/clusters_overview, redistribution test does not work.

Test Case: 1 jboss master and 2 jboss slaves. I created the "respostaCsu" queue in the artemis and posted a message on it. The message arrived on slave-1. This had no associated listeners for their correlationId and for this reason did not remove the message from the queue. The message should be forwarded to the next cluster machine (slave-2) according to the RedHat (redistribution-delay = 0 and message-load-balancing-type = ON_DEMAND) documentation. However the message was not redirected and remained in slave-1.

Any suggestion?

JBoss EAP 7.1 master domain.xml file:

```
...
<socket-binding-group name="full-ha-sockets" default-interface="public">
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="iiop" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
    <socket-binding name="iiop-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" interface="private" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" interface="private" port="7600"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" interface="private" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
    <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.modcluster.multicast.address:224.0.1.105}" multicast-port="23364"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <socket-binding name="messaging-group" interface="private" port="5432" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="9876"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>

...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">
    <server name="default">
        <security enabled="false"/>
        <cluster user="mbuser" password="mbsenha"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" redistribution-delay="0"/>
        <address-setting name="jms.#" redistribution-delay="0"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <broadcast-group name="mb-broadcast-group" socket-binding="messaging-group" broadcast-period="2000" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <discovery-group name="mb-discovery-group" socket-binding="messaging-group" refresh-timeout="10000"/>
        <cluster-connection name="my-cluster" address="jms" connector-name="http-connector" use-duplicate-detection="false" message-load-balancing-type="ON_DEMAND" discovery-group="mb-discovery-group"/>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <jms-queue name="solicitacaoCsu" entries="java:/jms/queue/QL.REQ.BKLQ001Z" durable="false"/>
        <jms-queue name="respostaCsu" entries="java:/jms/queue/QL.RSP.BKLQ001Z" durable="false"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector" ha="true" block-on-acknowledge="true" reconnect-attempts="-1"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: Hey Eduardo, I'm not sure If I'm right or not but according to documentation `You use the redistribution-delay attribute to set how many milliseconds to wait after the last consumer is closed on a queue before redistributing messages from that queue to other nodes of the cluster that have **matching consumers**.` So you need to have matching consumers to work re-distribution to work on both the slaves

Comment: Thanks Abhijeet. The problem is: the message delivered contains correlationID=10. The slave-1 wait for correlationID=15 and slave-2 wait for correlationID=10. First, the message has delivered int the slave-1 and correlationID doesn't match. Slave-1 should forward this message to slave-2 (last consumer is closed). But the slave-1 don't redistribute the message. On the both slaves has consumers, but only one has the right correlationID.

Comment: If my answer addressed your question please mark it as "correct" to help others who have this same question in the future. If not, please provide feedback for what wasn't correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Redistribution doesn't support selectors. However, initial distribution does. Therefore you should create your consumer *before* you send the request so that the consumer is on the queue when the reply is sent.

Comment: Hi Justin. Thanks a lot. But I found the solution! The problem was "messaging-group" tag in socket-binding! I configured port=0, multicast-addres to 231.7.7.7 and redistribution-delay to 0. It's works!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. 
But I found the solution! The problem was "messaging-group" tag in socket-binding! I configured port=0, multicast-addres to 231.7.7.7 and redistribution-delay to 0. It's works! =)

Here is my Jboss CLI:

```
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/broadcast-group=bg-group1:remove
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/discovery-group=dg-group1:remove
/socket-binding-group=full-ha-sockets/socket-binding=messaging-group:add(port=0,multicast-address=${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7},multicast-port=${jboss.messaging.group.port:9876})
/socket-binding-group=full-ha-sockets/socket-binding=messaging-throughput:add(port=5455)

/profile=full-ha/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/broadcast-group=bg-group1:add(socket-binding=messaging-group,broadcast-period=5000,connectors=[http-connector])
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/discovery-group=dg-group1:add(socket-binding=messaging-group,refresh-timeout=10000)
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/address-setting=#:write-attribute(name=redistribution-delay,value=0)
```